# Having problems with Clipper 5.3 and Harbour

Tags: clipper

I am trying to develop again in Clipper 5.3 (last version I used was 5.2a) and Harbour. I have Harbour 3.2 and the path is set to the correct folder in my windows 11 system environment variables. I wrote a simple program trying to open a window with WOpen(x1,x2,y1,y2). Compiler is hbmk2 and the error is throwing is I don’t have the correct include.ch file that includes the WOpen() function. Please help.

Here is the code I used.

```
//Main.prg

CLS
WOpen(5,5,20,72)
Inkey()
Return
```